# How to glue 3 rows in one string?

Tags: sql-server-2005

In table pics I have 3 different rows, where surname, name and middle name are stored. 
In query I need to glue them to one string:

```
pics.e_family + ' ' + pics.e_name + ' ' + pics.e_sname AS fio
```

All works perfectly, but one entry don't have middle name at all (no mistake, its really so). And in fio I get NULL. Is there any possibility to modify code, or make additional check if one or more of the rows are null, replace it with space symbol or just show remain rows?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean columns instead of rows in your title and the first sentence? Also,  what does _"or just show remain rows"_ mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean columns instead of rows, you can use `COALESCE` or `ISNULL`:

```
pics.e_family + ' ' + COALESCE(pics.e_name, '') + ' ' + pics.e_sname AS fio
```

Comment: @robnick: now your edited comment appears as if it's  referring to my answer ;)

Comment: No no your answer is awesome! It will produce an extra space between first and last name if e_name is null but I'm too tired to correct.